# Postgres: Difference of a value in two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Database: PostgreSQL

Question: I have two tables: Table `TabA` and Table `TabB`
Both have a common column name `ColX` which is unique in `TabA` but could have multiple entries in `TabB`

I need to find the count of rows/values when it *(value in "ColX")* occurs in `TabA` but not in `TabB`

The simple scenario is when a value *(value in "ColX")* process successfully in `TabA` then it goes in `TabB` and have child processes.

If that value *(value in "ColX")* fails in `TabA` it then **does not go** in "TabB".

I need to find count of such failed values

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Why don't you provide some sample data and your expected output in table format rather than describing so many things

Answer (score 0):

I think,you must this query :

```
Select a.* from TabA as a where a.ColX Not IN(Select b.ColX from TabB as b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend `NOT EXISTS` for this purpose:

```
select count(*)
from tabA a
where not exists (select 1 from tabB b where b.colX = a.colX);
```

I strongly discourage using `NOT IN` with subqueries.  `NOT IN` returns no rows whatsoever if the subquery has even on `NULL` value.  `NOT EXISTS` behaves as expected in this situation.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys for helping out..
For some reason both above did not work. not sure mechanism behind it..
however below worked..

SELECT COUNT(ColX) FROM TabA WHERE ColX NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(ColX) FROM TabB)

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Putting one of the columns between parentheses changes nothing. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` and `distinct a,b` - besides it's not really necessary for a NOT IN to begin with.